# Wordpress Author Page 404

Tags: wordpress

I am having a problem with listing all post by given author in `author.php`
Everything works OK for all user, except admin.

http://somedomain.com/author/MyUser - OK (non admin user!)
http://somedomain.com/author/?author=1 - OK (admin ID = 1)

http://somedomain.com/author/admin - 404
http://somedomain.com/author/User.Admin - 404
http://somedomain.com/author/AdminNickName - 404

The `wp_query` as follow:

```
$curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));

$args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'author' =>$curauth->ID, 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Any solutions? Many thanks!

Comment: Does your admin user have posts? Security tip rename the admin user, every hacker tries to hack the 'admin' account first. if you have 'admin_guy' it at least is a bit harder to figure out. http://mrwweb.com/wordpress-tip-dont-use-admin-seriously/

Comment: try to disable all plugin's and try again.

Comment: @janw - no plugins, same issue. Any suggestions or workaround?

Comment: weird.. No idea how to fix this

Comment: Have you tried disabling permalinks and the re-enable them?

Comment: Reseting permalinks helped!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Here's the solution below. (I'm not sure why this works, but it does.)

Edit your Wordpress database table wp_users. Find your admin account and edit the "user_nicename" field. Put in your login name (or some URL friendly string) and save it.

That's it. On mine, the original value in that column was "Trevor Gehman" and the url for the author page was /author/TrevorGehman/ which returned a 404. I changed the value to "trevorgehman" and then the url became /author/trevorgehman/ and it worked!

http://wphacks.com/change-author-archive-permalink/